# JSON element save to variable

Tags: php, json, variables

I have a JSON in a URL, that return this:

```
[{"id":"aabbcc","name":"aabbcc"}]

$json = file_get_contents('http:localhost/myapp/aabbcc/config'):
$config = json_decode($json, true);
```

I want save the parameter 'id' in a variable:

This is correct?

```
$id = $config['id'];
```

Comment: For that JSON string it is more likely to be a `$config[0]['id']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Var `$config` will be an array with single associated array.

You should get first assoc. array and then `id` key of it:

```
$id = $config[0]['id'];
```

Comment: In this case it would actually be `$config[0]['id']` since `true` argument is passed as second parameter to `json_decode()` in the example.  This forces object conversion to associative array.